# Density of a substance

Tags: density, buoyancy

I have faced a question related to Archimides' principle which is all about a car sunk in water. They said calculate the average density of the car, but i really don't what does an average density mean. Any help?

Comment: Have you looked at [Wikipedia's article on density?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since a car is made up of many different materials, which all likely have their own different densities, the density of the car is, therefore, not the same everywhere. The average density is the density such that, were the entire car to be that density, it would have the same volume and mass.

It is very easy to figure out. The total mass of the car divided by the total volume gives you an average density for the entire car.

That is:

$$\rho_{av}=\frac{M_{total}}{V_{total}}$$

Comment: It is clear now...Thanks for the answer. I just got confused about that because I thought that it may be related to buoyant force.

Comment: And don't forget the mass of any trapped air (probably not significant) and especially the volume of any trapped air.

Comment: @James that would reduce the average density more so because it would increase buoyancy. I'm assuming that the scenario allows for the car to completely fill with water, and that the cabin cavity is not included in the calculation

Comment: either way, the strategy and formula remains the same

Comment: @Jim I understand what you mean.  However, there may be some not-so-obvious air such as in the tires.

Comment: @James good point.

Answer (score 0):

The average density is the average amount of mass (which means materials and stuff) in a certain amount of space.In a simpler explaination it means how compact something is. All you must do is sink your car in water, see how much the water level rises, which would give you the volume and then you divide the mass of the car by the volume it displaces.I got a picture to simply explain the formula.

[image]